# grep regex ignoring middle section

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file with recipient names like this

To: john smith (johny)

To: jane doe (jane)

To: Richard Larach (dick)

I want the matching to return just the nickname:

johny

jane

dick

I am trying to have regex match for the To: and ( ignoring the middle part, outputting only the nickname if matched.

I have tried

```
grep -e "To:*\("
grep -e "To: * \("
grep -e /To: * \(/
```

I'm not sure if the problem is the spaces, or I'm messing up somewhere else. I also can not just match the ( since there are other occurrences of (

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what do you want to do with the matches? Do you need to keep only the nicknames, or want the lines having a nickname?

Comment: Will reflect that in the edit. I just want the nickname part

Comment: BTW, `grep` uses regular expressions, not glob patterns, so "*" isn’t a match-all, it means “match zero or more of the preceding item”.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want just the nickname part try following command:

```
sed "s/.*(\(.*\))$/\1/g" input_filename
```

This will work only in case there is a single pair of (). In case of multiple pairs please use cut (given the line ends with nickname

```
rev input_filename | cut -d \( -f1 | cut -d \) -f2 | rev
```

In case you have some other pattern request you to add more samples in the input

Answer (score 0):

The grep command is just a filter for text file lines, so it only selects and outputs entire lines that matches; to cut out pieces you want, you need "sed", (or better yet, switch to perl).

`grep "To:[^(]*(${nickname})"` Matches the nicknames you want.

`sed 's/To:[^(]*(\([^)]*\))/\1/g'` actually replaces every full entry with nickname.

Here, the "`[^(]*`" and "`[^)]*`" part means any string that doesn't contain the left and the right parentheses.

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If using `gnu grep` is an option,  you could make use of `\K` to forget what was previously matched and a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert what follows is a closing parenthesis.

```
grep -Po '\bTo:.*?\(\K[^()]+(?=\))' inputfile
```

Comment: The "-P" option is not in POSIX, so what platform were you using?

Comment: @DannyNiu The is example is making use of `gnu grep`. I have updated my answer.